# Is there any structure in matrices computed from eigen vectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{nn}$ be a positive definite matrix with eigen value decomposition so that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{V}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{V}^T=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{\lambda}_{k}^{}\mathbf{v}_{k}^{}\mathbf{v}_{k}^T= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{B}_{k} 
\end{equation}

and we find the row-column location of largest entry of $\mathbf{A}$ i-e $a_{pq}=max(A_{ij}),\forall 1\leq i,j\leq n$.

Knowing this location, can we say something similar about the maximum entries of matrices $\mathbf{B_k}=\mathbf{\lambda}_{k}^{}\mathbf{v}_{k}^{}\mathbf{v}_{k}^T, \forall k=1,…,n$.

In other words, is there any mathematical work that proves that the pattern of data entries in original matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is also replicated in the matrices that are constructed using it EVD. 
This might not sound very useful to general audience, but will be useful for my particular problem

Comment: Probably not, consider the case where matrix $A$ is diagonal, then each $B_k$ has only one non-zero element, but each will be at a different location. I am curious about the underlying problem, could you give some more details?

Comment: Diagonal matrix is a good example. I should have thought about it. I am solving a minimization problem and my soluting is coming from the eigen vectors of +def matrix. The entries in solution mimics the $\mathbf{A}$. But I want to change it. one way is to include some constraint in the original optimization problem.  But I thought that this might have something to do with the EVD so thats why I asked